# Can we infer śatakratu शतक्रतु as a person with a wisdom in 100 ways?

Tags: vedas

One of the meaning of kratu is Enlightenment.

According to Sanskirt dictionary [Kavikratu](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=kavikratu&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) means having insight of a wise man.

Rig veda [III.37.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03037.htm), dedicated to Indra,  says:

> नामानि ते **शतक्रतो** विश्वाभिर्गीर्भिरीमहे | इन्द्राभिमातिषाह्ये ||
>
> O Indra, Lord of Hundred Powers, with all our songs we invocate Thy
>   names for triumph over foes.

Can we infer  śatakratu शतक्रतु means, a person with a wisdom in 100 ways?

Comment: it means doer of 100 yajnas

Comment: This should be the title: "Can we infer śatakratu शतक्रतु as a person with a wisdom in 100 ways?" if you already know other meanings. Your title allows for meanings you already know.

Answer (score 4):

शतक्रतु (śatakratu) means '**the one who has completed 100 yajnas (Ashvamedhas)**', this is the basic qualification for the post of Indra. Anyone who completes 100 Ashvamedha yajnas, attains the post of Indra.

---

References:

[Meaning in context of Rigveda](http://swaadhyaaya.blogspot.com/2019/02/the-sacred.html?m=1)

[Dictionary meaning](https://www.bsarkari.com/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%81--meaning-eng-299420)

Comment: Please read the content in the question part again.  I know the meaning of satakratu that you had provided - the one who has completed 100 yajnas (Ashvamedhas).  I am looking for  deeper meaning @Lakhi

Answer (score -1):

Indra was referred to as *śatakratu शतक्रतु*, which was commonly understood as one who did 100 yagnas.

Rig veda III.37.3, dedicated to Indra, says:

> नामानि ते शतक्रतो विश्वाभिर्गीर्भिरीमहे | इन्द्राभिमातिषाह्ये ||
>
> O Indra, Lord of Hundred Powers, with all our songs we invocate Thy
>   names for triumph over foes.

[Kratu (क्रतु)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kratu#sanskrit) means *resolve, will, determination or resolution or Enlightenment*, apart from sacrifice or *yagna*.

According to Sanskirt dictionary Kavikratu means *having insight of a wise man*.

We can infer  śatakratu शतक्रतु means, *a person with a wisdom or capacity or will to do things  in 100 ways*.

It is similar like eulogising God as  [*sahasraksha* - having 1000 eyes or *sahasrasirsha*](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/vedas/purusha_suktam.php) - having 1000 heads.

**Indra was eulogised as Brahman** [(Rig veda 2.1.3)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_2/Hymn_1) in Vedas.   The Brahman will be having the ability to do any thing in many (100) ways.

That was the reason calling Indra as śatakratu शतक्रतु.